# Is Spring for android being developed?

Tags: android, spring-android

I have android app in which I use Rest Remplate from Spring for Android. I also use OkHttpClient.

I'm planning to upgrade OkHttpClient library in my app to 3.9.x but this uses OkHttpClient3, RestTempkate uses OkHttpClient 2.x.

Last version of Spring for Android is dated few years ago - so my question:

Is spring for Android still developed?

If not should you suggest other library as Rest Client for android?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2.x milestone versions on maven central:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.android/spring-android-rest-template

```
2.0.0.M4    Spring Milestones   1   (Jul, 2017)
2.0.0.M3    Spring Milestones   4   (Jul, 2015)
2.0.0.M2    Spring Milestones   1   (Dec, 2014)
2.0.0.M1    Spring Milestones   2   (Sep, 2014)
```

It seems that with the latest OkHttpClient 3.x might be compatible.

A better place to ask might be github:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tkruse. 
This 2.0.0.M4 version is compatible with OkHttp3Client. I thought
 thah 2.0.0.M3 is the last version due to info at http://projects.spring.io/spring-android :)